# How can I include a function to count the guessing number?

Tags: python, loops

Instructions for the program:

Write a program that generates a random number in the range of 1 through 100, and asks the user to guess what the number is. If the user’s guess is higher than the random number, the program should display “Too high, try again.” If the user’s guess is lower than the random number, the program should display “Too low, try again.” If the user guesses the number, the application should congratulate the user and generate a new random number so the game can start over. The game needs to keep count of the number of guesses that the user makes. When the user decides to stop playing, the number of correct guesses should be displayed.

So far I've completed most of the code, I'm just missing a function to count the guessing times

```
def main():
  print("********* Welcome to the random number guessing game *********")
  run_game()
  play_again() 

def run_game():  
  #Importing the random module 
  import random
  #Generation of a random number
  n = random.randrange(1,100)
  #User guess the random number 
  guess = int(input("Enter any number: "))
  while n!= guess:
    if guess < n:
        print("Too low")
        guess = int(input("Enter number again: "))
    elif guess > n:
        print("Too high!")
        guess = int(input("Enter number again: "))
    else:
      break
  print("you guessed it right!!")
def play_again():
    while True:
        retry = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
        if retry == "yes":
            main()
        if retry == "no":
            print("Good game! Next time you won't beat me!")
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either yes or no")

main()
```

Comment: Surely you can see where you have the user enter a guess.  If you add `guesses += 1` after that, you will have a count of the guesses.  Note that you should not have three different places to enter a number.  Just do it once, so you only have to count once.

Comment: Did you notice that your function flow logic is recursive? You probably don't want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the number of guesses is easily done with a variable that exists as long as the game is running. For each guess, it needs to be incremented.

As this is obviously a homework question, please take a moment to think how you can apply this to your code before reading on.

Thank you. I'm also not going to post a complete answer but it should be obvious what to do to make it work.

I took the liberty of restructuring your code somewhat. Don't just copy and paste it as is but try to understand what I changed and why.

The issues I tried to address are:

- Recursive call: `main` calls `play_again` calls `main` calls `play_again` etc. None of these return until you quit the program. This may (if you play *a lot*) cause python to raise an exception. I eliminated `play_again`.
- Move `import` to top of the file. This is where it's usually done in python.
- Fix range. `random.randrange` excludes the end point (as opposed to `random.randint`, which does)
- Play again? also accepts single letter answers ('y' or 'n') as well as capital letters.

So here's my take on your code:

```py
import random  # better do it once, at the top of the file


def main():
    while True:
        run_game()
        retry = input("Would you like to play again?: ").lower()  # accept capital letters
        if retry in ["y", "yes"]:  # y is also fine
            pass
        if retry in ["n", "no"]:
            print("Good game! Next time you won't beat me!")
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either yes or no")


def run_game():
    print("********* Welcome to the random number guessing game *********")
    n = random.randrange(1, 101)  # note that randrange does *not* include the end point
    guess = int(input("Enter any number: "))
    num_guesses = 1  # this is the number of guesses
    while n != guess:
        if guess < n:
            print("Too low")
        elif guess > n:
            print("Too high!")
        else:
            break
        guess = int(input("Enter number again: "))
        # TODO do something with num_guesses

    print(f"you guessed it right, it took you {num_guesses} guesses!!")


if __name__ == '__main__':  # only call main when you run this file
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can write code in better way, Anyway just you have add line in your code

```
 guess = int(input("Enter any number: "))
 count_guessing=0 ### add new line to your code #####
  while n!= guess:
    if guess < n:
        print("Too low")
        count_guessing+=1 ### add new line to your code #####
        guess = int(input("Enter number again: "))
    elif guess > n:
        print("Too high!")
        count_guessing+=1 ### add new line to your code #####
        guess = int(input("Enter number again: "))
    else:
        print(count_guessing)
      break
```